# Inverse of the outer product of some vectors with their transpose

Tags: matrices, outer-product

Assume i have $n$ 3D unit vectors $v_s$, with different values.
Then i define a matrix $T$ as:

$$
T = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{s=1}^{n} v_s \times v_s' 
$$
where $v_s$ are $3\times 1$ vectors and therefore $T$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix.

How can i find a possible set of vectors $v_s$ if a positive definite diagonal matrix $T$ (with $trace=1$) is given? (any numerical or non-exact method is acceptable)

Comment: Since $T$ is diagonal, won't it work to take the $v_s$ to be of the form $(\alpha,0,0)$ or with the entries permuted? Unless the diagonal of $T$ has negative entries ... it might be that $T$ being positive definite is a necessary condition. PS: the $\frac1n$ is a red herring—its contribution can be absorbed into the chosen vectors.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks. Since they are unit vectors, having two zeros is not possible because then the remaining entry becomes 1 after the normalization. Yes, T is positive definite and its trace is 1.